# Tab app - how to make associations between page / client

Tags: facebook

I'm looking to build an app that gets installed as a tab and is used by different clients. Depending on which client installs this app, different data gets displayed. I've read that the appropriate way of doing customization like this is by associating the page id with the client id. Couple questions:

1. Is this indeed a correct way of thinking?
2. Is there a different way of passing data to the installed app like query string args or something like that where I could use that to customize what to pull? Seems like you would have to build several different apps to reflect the url differences but could be totally wrong

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally correct flow for such functionality.

Once Page Tab application is loaded it will receive [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) (via `POST` data) which will include details about the Page application is running on.

To pass data to your Application running in Page Tab `app_data` argument need to be used ([read documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)).

Comment: I read that but didn't quite understand how the app_data argument got used since when you install the app to the tab using the link: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Comment: The `app_data` is used when you're linking users to a page tab and want certain values passed through - but you should have enough data from other parts of the `signed_request` to know which App/Page combination to display the data for - specifically `page` inside the signed_request which tells you the page ID, and whether the current user is a fan and/or admin of the page

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can read `signed_request` once my tab is in FB chrome but how do I get the Tab Edit Page in FB chrome? It always open in a new window without any get or post data so I have no way of knowing, which page is trying to edit stuff ...